# How to use bool to limit Elasticsearch query results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

In my Rails app I have 2 models: User(id) & Document(id,user_id, document_title,document)

```
  def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['document_title^10', 'document']
          }
        },
      }
  end
```

I'm using the above search query which works great for return results across the entire table. The problem is, the results are not limited to the current_user. I'm trying to update the search method to only return results for the current_user. Per the docs, I'm doing:

```
  def self.search(query, user_id)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
      {
        bool: {
          filter: ["user_id", user_id]
        },
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: query,
            fields: ['document_title^10', 'document']
          }
        },
      }
  end
```

However, that is erroring with:

```
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. unknown search element [bool]","line":1,"col":2}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"documents","node":"52GAD0HbT4OlekjesTZY_A","reason":{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. unknown search element [bool]","line":1,"col":2}}]},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what docs you are looking at but that query isn't right: the multi match query should be in the must clause of the bool query.

```
{
   query: {
     bool: {
       must: [{
        multi_match: {...}
      }],
      filter: [{
        term: {user_id: user_id}
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Are any updates required to the index to make this work? Thanks

Comment: hmm, I'm getting "unknown search element [bool]"

Comment: The query does need to go inside the `query` top level element